# SQL Server Common function for getting max(id)

Tags: sql-server, t-sql

In my application many I time we use MAX(). How can I write a common function where I can pass table name and column name and get MAX().
I mean single function for any table/field.

Thanks,
Tanmay.

Comment: Do you want this as a T-SQL sproc, or in some client language?

Answer (score 0):

In MSSQL there are no [particularly elegant](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1609115/pass-table-as-parameter-into-sql-server-udf) ways to use UDFs with dynamic table/field names, so personally I would just stick to a simple `SELECT MAX()`.

If the IDs are `IDENTITY` columns you can just use `IDENT_CURRENT('the_table')`