# SQL - Pass Table to a UDF in a Select

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2008, parameters, user-defined-functions

I have a UDF that takes a table as a parameter (a 2 column table) and outputs a string, much like this [article](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1609115/pass-table-as-parameter-into-sql-server-udf).  I have a table that I want to apply the UDF over multiple columns like this:

```
Date   Unit   Line   Revenue   Orders
4/1/12 D      R      20.00     3
4/2/12 D      R      25.00     4
4/1/12 H      W      33.00     1
4/2/12 H      W      35.00     3
```

I want to call my UDF on every row of this table that has the most current date and pass the UDF a table with the columns Date and Revenue for each distinct Unit and Line.  And I also want to call the UDF and pass Date and Orders for each distinct Unit and Line.  This is a report and the UDF will always get passed the Date column and another column that I want to apply some calculation to and store and report.  So I have looked at a lot of things including CROSS APPLY and I want to do something like this:

```
SELECT        T.unit
              , T.line
              , dbo.fn_myUDF((SELECT T2.Date, T2.Revenue FROM #Table T2)) as UDFRevenueResult
              , dbo.fn_myUDF((SELECT T2.Date, T2.Orders FROM #Table T2)) as UDFOrderResult
FROM          #Table T
WHERE         T.Date = @ReportDate
```

This gives me the error "Only one expression can be specified in the select list when the subquery is not introduced with EXISTS."  I looked at CROSS APPLY but that seems only apply for when you are returning a table variable.  So I could probably answer my own question by using a cursor and a loop maybe and constructing each table I want to pass to the UDF in each loop iteration but that just doesn't seem right.  Can anyone give me an idea how to do what I want in SQL Server 2008?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Subqueries can't be used like that to return table variables in the SELECT portion of the query.  They can only return a single value.  As in:

```
set @myParam = (select myvalue from table where primarykey = 1)
```

or

```
set @myParam = (select top 1 myvalue from table)
```

But, considering that your subqueries do not have any relation to the rows being selected, you can do something like this.

```
declare @t1 table (DateTime c1, float c2)
insert @t1
SELECT Date, Revenue 
FROM #Table 

declare @t2 table (DateTime c1, int c2) -- not sure on data type of 'Orders'
insert @t2
SELECT Date, Orders FROM #Table


SELECT T.unit               
     , T.line               
     , dbo.fn_myUDF(@t1) as UDFRevenueResult               
     , dbo.fn_myUDF(@t2) as UDFOrderResult 
FROM #Table T 
WHERE T.Date = @ReportDate
```

Comment: I was afraid of that.  Is there a way I can split my table up into sub-tables by distinct Unit and Line easily?  Or will I just have to create a table for each Unit/Line and column I want to pass my UDF?

Comment: @deusxmach1na - are you trying to treat each row as a table?

Comment: Not each row, but all rows with the same Unit and Line should be a table.  My UDF will take the Date column and the Revenue column and do a calculation on it which I want it to perform for every distinct Unit and Line value.  So in my example table I would want the first two rows as one table since they are Unit D and Line R, and the next two rows as another table since they are Unit H and line W.

Comment: I got a working solution now, thanks!  I used ROW_NUMBER() OVER (PARTITION BY Unit, Line ORDER BY Date DESC) to put a 1 in every row where I want to start a new table and iterated through that column to build up my tables.  Anyway you answered my original question so thanks!

Comment: One quick note.  `DECLARE @t1 TABLE` should be `DECLARE @t1 as dbo.MyTableType` since my UDF expects to get my specific TableType as a parameter.