# Returning data from SQL server 2008 User defined table types using PHP v. 5.4

Tags: php, sql-server-2008

Using PHP v. 5.4, I am trying to connect to a SQL 2008 database and insert into and then return data from a SQL user defined table type.

The SQL table data type is defined as follows:
`create type ScreensTableType as table(ElementCode decimal(6,2), ElementYear int, MinimumValue float, MaximumValue float, AndOr bit)`

And a pared down version of my PHP code is:

```
<?php
$sqlStr='';
$serverName = "Server"; //serverName\instanceName
$connectionInfo = array( "Database"=>"Db");
$conn = sqlsrv_connect( $serverName, $connectionInfo);

if(!$conn ) {
     echo "Connection could not be established.<br />";
     die( print_r( sqlsrv_errors(), true));
}    
$sqlStr="declare @ScreensParam [ScreensTableType] insert @ScreensParam values (5101.00,2011,0,100,1),(5103.00,2011,0,100,1) select * from @ScreensParam";
  // print $sqlStr;
$getFormData=sqlsrv_query($conn, $sqlStr);

if( $getFormData === false )
{
      if( ($errors = sqlsrv_errors() ) != null)
      {
         foreach( $errors as $error)
         {
            echo "SQLSTATE: ".$error[ 'SQLSTATE']."\n";
            echo "code: ".$error[ 'code']."\n";
            echo "message: ".$error[ 'message']."\n";
         }
      }
}

     while( $row = sqlsrv_fetch_array( $getFormData, SQLSRV_FETCH_ASSOC) ) {
       print '####'.$row['ElementCode'];

     }
?>
```

The connection works and no errors are returned. However nothing at all is returned. If I print and run the $sqlStr in Management Studio it works fine. If I change the $sqlStr to `"select top 10 * from someExistingDbTable"` then I get data returned.

Does anybody have any ideas on how to do this or what I might be doing wrong?

Thanks very much,

Dan

**Part 2**
Here's what I'm trying to do - the sp returns requested financial data from a web form.   A user chooses the following options from a form:

```
"financial item", "financial year", "minimum value", "maximum value", "and/or"  
Revenue, 2010, 1000000, 10000000, 'and'  
EPS, 2011, 0.5, 1.5, 'or'
```

There could be 1 row or 50 rows depending on the users request.  I want to load those items into a UDTT. In the stored procedure I create a dynamic query. A cursor iterates over the rows of the UDTT and creates the conditions in the where clause of the dynamic query. The data is then returned.

The problem I'm having is I don't seem to be able to get PHP to return any results when I use the UDTT. I just used the simplified example above to see if anyone could get data returned.

I should add that when I print the "real" string I'm passing from PHP to SQL the stored procedure does return data. And that my connection to SQL is good.

**Third and final part**
I should have prefaced the original question by saying I'm a complete novice when it comes to PHP. Not bad at SQL though.

OK here's what I've tried:

SQL with no UDTT

```
drop procedure testUDTT

go

create PROCEDURE [testUDTT]
as
SET NOCOUNT ON
select XmlRequest = '###Data Returned###'

go
```

if I run the following PHP code data is returned:

```
$select="exec testUDTT";
$sqlResponse=sqlsrv_query($conn, $select);
while( $row = sqlsrv_fetch_array( $sqlResponse, SQLSRV_FETCH_ASSOC) ) {
  print '####'.$row['XmlRequest'];
  }
```

If I change $select to:

```
$select="declare @ScreensParam [ScreensTableType] exec testUDTT";
```

data is returned.

However if I change $select to:

```
$select="declare @ScreensParam [ScreensTableType] insert @ScreensParam values (5101.00,2011,0,100,1),(5103.00,2011,0,100,1) exec testUDTT";
```

**NO** data is returned and there are no errors???. I suspect SQL wants a "GO" between the "insert" and "exec" statements although this works fine when I run from SSMS.

I was thinking about this another way as well. If the above stored procedure had one input param like an int eg:

```
create PROCEDURE [testUDTT]
@InputInt int
as
SET NOCOUNT ON
if @InputInt > 0
  select XmlRequest = '###Data Returned###'
```

my PHP code could look something like:

```
$inputInt=1;
$select="exec testUDTT @InputInt=?";
$params = array(
  array($inputInt, SQLSRV_PARAM_IN)
  );
$sqlResponse=sqlsrv_query($conn, $select, $params);
```

Now If I had this stored procedure using a UDTT:

```
create PROCEDURE [testUDTT]
@ScreensParam ScreensTableType READONLY
as
SET NOCOUNT ON
select XmlRequest = '###Data Returned###'
from @ScreensParam

go
```

and I try to break the PHP call to sql into 2 parts (not sure if this is correct, but gave it a try):

```
$add='declare @ScreensParam [ScreensTableType] insert @ScreensParam values (5101.00,2011,0,100,1),(5103.00,2011,0,100,1)';
$select='exec testUDTT @ScreensParam='.$screensParam;

sqlsrv_query($conn, $add);
$sqlResponse=sqlsrv_query($conn, $select);
```

I get the following error: `SQLSTATE: 42000 code: 137 message: [Microsoft][SQL Server Native Client 11.0][SQL Server]Must declare the scalar variable "@ScreensParam".` as I guess the UDTT is not in scope.
Also I wonder what the PHP syntax should be for passing @ScreensParam in the array? Would $select become `exec testUDTT @ScreensParam=?` where `"?" = '@ScreensParam'`. Don't know?

So I've found a solution creating XML instead of using UDTT which is acceptable. And I've spent more than enough time trying to get it to work. I have a sneaking suspicion that what I want to do can't be done with PHP currently.

If anyone has/finds a solution though, I'd love to know.

Thanks for the help Fuzzy Button. It was fun trying.

Using PHP v. 5.4, I am trying to connect to a SQL 2008 database and insert into and then return data from a SQL user defined table type.

The SQL table data type is defined as follows:
`create type ScreensTableType as table(ElementCode decimal(6,2), ElementYear int, MinimumValue float, MaximumValue float, AndOr bit)`

And a pared down version of my PHP code is:

```
<?php
$sqlStr='';
$serverName = "Server"; //serverName\instanceName
$connectionInfo = array( "Database"=>"Db");
$conn = sqlsrv_connect( $serverName, $connectionInfo);

if(!$conn ) {
     echo "Connection could not be established.<br />";
     die( print_r( sqlsrv_errors(), true));
}    
$sqlStr="declare @ScreensParam [ScreensTableType] insert @ScreensParam values (5101.00,2011,0,100,1),(5103.00,2011,0,100,1) select * from @ScreensParam";
  // print $sqlStr;
$getFormData=sqlsrv_query($conn, $sqlStr);

if( $getFormData === false )
{
      if( ($errors = sqlsrv_errors() ) != null)
      {
         foreach( $errors as $error)
         {
            echo "SQLSTATE: ".$error[ 'SQLSTATE']."\n";
            echo "code: ".$error[ 'code']."\n";
            echo "message: ".$error[ 'message']."\n";
         }
      }
}

     while( $row = sqlsrv_fetch_array( $getFormData, SQLSRV_FETCH_ASSOC) ) {
       print '####'.$row['ElementCode'];

     }
?>
```

The connection works and no errors are returned. However nothing at all is returned. If I print and run the $sqlStr in Management Studio it works fine. If I change the $sqlStr to `"select top 10 * from someExistingDbTable"` then I get data returned.

Does anybody have any ideas on how to do this or what I might be doing wrong?

Thanks very much,

Dan

**Part 2**
Here's what I'm trying to do - the sp returns requested financial data from a web form.   A user chooses the following options from a form:

```
"financial item", "financial year", "minimum value", "maximum value", "and/or"  
Revenue, 2010, 1000000, 10000000, 'and'  
EPS, 2011, 0.5, 1.5, 'or'
```

There could be 1 row or 50 rows depending on the users request.  I want to load those items into a UDTT. In the stored procedure I create a dynamic query. A cursor iterates over the rows of the UDTT and creates the conditions in the where clause of the dynamic query. The data is then returned.

The problem I'm having is I don't seem to be able to get PHP to return any results when I use the UDTT. I just used the simplified example above to see if anyone could get data returned.

I should add that when I print the "real" string I'm passing from PHP to SQL the stored procedure does return data. And that my connection to SQL is good.

**Third and final part**
I should have prefaced the original question by saying I'm a complete novice when it comes to PHP. Not bad at SQL though.

OK here's what I've tried:

SQL with no UDTT

```
drop procedure testUDTT

go

create PROCEDURE [testUDTT]
as
SET NOCOUNT ON
select XmlRequest = '###Data Returned###'

go
```

if I run the following PHP code data is returned:

```
$select="exec testUDTT";
$sqlResponse=sqlsrv_query($conn, $select);
while( $row = sqlsrv_fetch_array( $sqlResponse, SQLSRV_FETCH_ASSOC) ) {
  print '####'.$row['XmlRequest'];
  }
```

If I change $select to:

```
$select="declare @ScreensParam [ScreensTableType] exec testUDTT";
```

data is returned.

However if I change $select to:

```
$select="declare @ScreensParam [ScreensTableType] insert @ScreensParam values (5101.00,2011,0,100,1),(5103.00,2011,0,100,1) exec testUDTT";
```

**NO** data is returned and there are no errors???. I suspect SQL wants a "GO" between the "insert" and "exec" statements although this works fine when I run from SSMS.

I was thinking about this another way as well. If the above stored procedure had one input param like an int eg:

```
create PROCEDURE [testUDTT]
@InputInt int
as
SET NOCOUNT ON
if @InputInt > 0
  select XmlRequest = '###Data Returned###'
```

my PHP code could look something like:

```
$inputInt=1;
$select="exec testUDTT @InputInt=?";
$params = array(
  array($inputInt, SQLSRV_PARAM_IN)
  );
$sqlResponse=sqlsrv_query($conn, $select, $params);
```

Now If I had this stored procedure using a UDTT:

```
create PROCEDURE [testUDTT]
@ScreensParam ScreensTableType READONLY
as
SET NOCOUNT ON
select XmlRequest = '###Data Returned###'
from @ScreensParam

go
```

and I try to break the PHP call to sql into 2 parts (not sure if this is correct, but gave it a try):

```
$add='declare @ScreensParam [ScreensTableType] insert @ScreensParam values (5101.00,2011,0,100,1),(5103.00,2011,0,100,1)';
$select='exec testUDTT @ScreensParam='.$screensParam;

sqlsrv_query($conn, $add);
$sqlResponse=sqlsrv_query($conn, $select);
```

I get the following error: `SQLSTATE: 42000 code: 137 message: [Microsoft][SQL Server Native Client 11.0][SQL Server]Must declare the scalar variable "@ScreensParam".` as I guess the UDTT is not in scope.
Also I wonder what the PHP syntax should be for passing @ScreensParam in the array? Would $select become `exec testUDTT @ScreensParam=?` where `"?" = '@ScreensParam'`. Don't know?

So I've found a solution creating XML instead of using UDTT which is acceptable. And I've spent more than enough time trying to get it to work. I have a sneaking suspicion that what I want to do can't be done with PHP currently.

If anyone has/finds a solution though, I'd love to know.

Thanks for the help Fuzzy Button. It was fun trying.

Comment: Possibly you can't perform multiple operations (non-query) in the query command? You may have to put it in a Stored Proc and call that instead?

Comment: Not completely sure I understand. Are you saying that it might not be working because I have a declare, insert, and select all within the same query command? Originally I had the declare and insert commands and then ran a stored procedure that used the inserted rows in @ScreensParam as input params, however I was getting no output with that so tried to make it as simple as possible.

Comment: OK perhaps in simplifying, I created another problem. So here's the gist. Originally I had $sqlStr as:  `$sqlStr="declare @ScreensParam [ScreensTableType] insert @ScreensParam values (5101.00,2011,0,100,1),(5103.00,2011,0,100,1) exec xml_testIndustry 1, 2009, 2011, @ScreensParam";`  What I'm wondering is how do I pass the @ScreensParam to the stored procedure as a user defined table type?

Comment: I can't get it working at all :)  ... see http://sqlfiddle.com/#!3/b1596/14

Comment: I suspect this has something to do with the database owner. For example if I run:  `create type MyTableType as table (val1 int, val2 int)
go

CREATE PROCEDURE [dbo].[sp_DummyProc]
as
BEGIN

 DECLARE @MyTable MyTableType

END`

Comment: I suspect this has something to do with the database owner. For example if I run:  `create type MyTableType as table (val1 int, val2 int)
go

CREATE PROCEDURE [dbo].[sp_DummyProc]
as
BEGIN

 DECLARE @MyTable MyTableType

END`  the owner of the table type is dbo however the owner of the sp in this case is me, so it doesn't work. I can't get it to work on sqlfiddle either, but I guarantee the code works.

Comment: Can you just put the whole lot in an SP and have just the Exec in the PHP query?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

OK after switching over to an XML solution, I was searching out how to do something else in PHP and serendipitously stumbled upon a question about using SQL temp tables with PHP and the response utilized the sqlsrv_next_result() function. So this now works beautifully:

```
$sqlStr=
  <<<SQL
    declare @ScreensParam [ScreensTableType]
    insert @ScreensParam values (5101.00,2011,-1000,1000,1),(5103.00,2011,0,100,1)
    exec xml_testIndustry '1,2', 2009, 2011, @ScreensParam
  SQL;

$getFormData=sqlsrv_query($conn, $sqlStr);
echo "Rows affected: " . sqlsrv_rows_affected($getFormData).'<br/>';

$next_result = sqlsrv_next_result($getFormData);
if( $next_result ) {
   while( $row = sqlsrv_fetch_array( $getFormData, SQLSRV_FETCH_ASSOC)){
      echo $row['XmlRequest'].": <br />"; 
   }
} elseif( is_null($next_result)) {
     echo "No more results.<br />";
} else {
     die(print_r(sqlsrv_errors(), true));
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I've been thinking this over.

First, I played with
`$sqlStr="DECLARE @test varchar(max) SET @test='123' SELECT * from table";`
and can confirm that multiple statements can indeed run OK :)

Second...

**EDIT**
Playing some more in http://sqlfiddle.com/#!3/b1596/73 it appears you can pass a table of values into a SQL command as a defined table type and execute an SP with the temporary table as a param... *(it took a lot of experimenting but I eventually found that sqlfiddle is very fussy about semi-colons and sometimes doesn't treat comments as comments!)*

```
create type ScreensTableType1 as table
 (ElementCode decimal(6,2), ElementYear int, MinimumValue float,
  MaximumValue float, AndOr bit);
```

An SP to demo a table parameter, that outputs what's passed in :

```
CREATE PROCEDURE testSP
  ( @ParamTab ScreensTableType1 Readonly )
AS 
begin
  SELECT * FROM @ParamTab
end;
```

Should be able to load multiple rows of data into the SP, in PHP...
One way : with a CTE :

```
DECLARE @S1 as ScreensTableType1
With data_in as
(
 SELECT
   5101.00 as ElementCode, 2011 as ElementYear,
   0 as MinimumValue, 100 as MaximumValue, 1 as AndOr
 UNION ALL 
 SELECT 5103.00,2011,0,100,1
)
INSERT @S1 SELECT * from data_in
Exec testSP @S1
```

.. or multiple INSERTs :

```
DECLARE @S2 as ScreensTableType1
insert @S2 values (5199.00,2011,0,100,1)
insert @S2 values (5177.00,2011,0,100,1)
EXEC testSP @S2
```

Comment: This is actually data being sent from a web form. So there may be 2 rows or there may be 50 depending on the users requests. I thought I'd try loading the requests into a sql user defined table type and then passing that to a stored procedure to return the data, but can't get it to work. I suppose I could instead build xml and pass the xml to the stored procedure, but it bugs me I can't get my original idea to work and I'm not sure why.

Comment: I've tried numerous varieties of `declare @ScreensParam ScreensTableType  INSERT INTO ...` as instructed at  http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1609115/pass-table-as-parameter-into-sql-server-udf amongst many others. It doesn't work in sqlfiddle (SQL Srv 2008). But a temp table did : `create table #S1
(ElementCode decimal(6...` - I could insert and select from that, but its not as elegant as the supposed @S1 alternative as it writes to the 'tempdb' database.

Comment: It's been really bugging me :) but I think I've got what you need... see the edited answer. I eventually found that sqlfiddle is very fussy about semi-colons and sometimes doesn't treat comments as comments!

Comment: Wow you just don't quit. I have the SQL part working doing the multiple inserts into the UDTT. However when I run the PHP code to query the output from the stored procedure I don't get any output. Did you have any luck with the PHP part?

Comment: Sorry, only have SQL2005 to use with PHP. I'll probably bow out at this point and wish you luck! ... but might be back :)

Comment: OK thanks for all the help. I'll spend some more time on it when I get a chance. Have to get this up and running, so for now will use an XML solution.

Comment: This one has really caught my imagination :) ... so, you've got the data into the SP using your UDTT, but does the SP do a `SELECT * FROM @UDTT_Param` (or equiv) at the end - to actually return the data.. and PHP isn't receiving it? Also, how vital is it to get the same data back in PHP that you've already sent SQL-wards? If you've already built the string to insert the data, can you just do a second SQL command to get it into the format you recquire? Or does the SP transform it in some way?

Comment: Sorry having a little trouble. See original question under**Part 2**

Comment: What happens if you put `SELECT 'hello' as test1` at the end of the SP? Does that come back into the PHP?

Comment: I put my final summations/comments in the original question under **Third and final part**