# SQL - create function that will take a table variable as an input

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql, function

I'm having trouble writing a function that will take a table variable as an input and return the total number of rows in that table.

Here is my try:

```
CREATE FUNCTION fTableRows( @table TABLE )
RETURNS INT AS
BEGIN
    RETURN( SELECT COUNT(*) FROM @table )
END
```

Answer (score 2):

If you do this in SQL server 2008 + you have use user defined data type - table.
Good explanation can be found here: [Pass table as parameter into SQL Udf](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1609115/pass-table-as-parameter-into-sql-server-udf)

Answer (score 2):

```
CREATE FUNCTION getTableRows
(
    @TableName VARCHAR(30)
)
RETURNS INT AS
BEGIN
    RETURN( SELECT COUNT(*) FROM @TableName)
END
```

Comment: I like this approach much better.  The function should definitely accept "table name" instead of "table", if at all possible.  IMHO...