# Scalar Function with select query as argument

Tags: sql-server, t-sql, sql-server-2008-r2

is it possible to have a function in SQL which accepts the result of a select Query?
like 
SCalarFunc(Select * from CustomQuery)

and also I want to make a another select query back from the Function?

can anybody  give a sample?

Comment: Are you using SQL Server and if yes then what version?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you are using `SQL Server 2008` and above then you can follow below sample code using [`User-Defined Table Types variable`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb522526.aspx)

```
-- Create first function to return the result of select query

create function fn_test()
returns table
as
return (select * from tab);

-- test it once
select * from dbo.fn_test()


--create a user defined table types
CREATE TYPE TableType 
AS TABLE (id int not null,
name varchar(10)); 


--create your second level function passing the 
--result of first function as table
CREATE FUNCTION fn_test_tab(@tabname TableType READONLY)
RETURNS VARCHAR(10)
AS
BEGIN
    DECLARE @name VARCHAR(10)

    SELECT @name = name FROM @tabname where id = 1;
    RETURN @name
END

--define a variable of created table type
DECLARE @tab TableType;

-- fill the data from first function
insert into @tab select * from dbo.fn_test();

--call your second function passing the table variable
SELECT dbo.fn_test_tab(@tab);
```

Sidenote: Tested in `SQL server 2008 R2 Express` and it works fine. Use of Table type concept is taken from [Pass table as parameter into sql server UDF](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1609115/pass-table-as-parameter-into-sql-server-udf)

Comment: Thank you for answer, I am just newbie in that subject. where should create TableTypeand fn_test_tab? TableType in User-Defined Table Types ? fn_test_tab in Scalar Valued Functions?is that correct?

Comment: Yes, just follow the same way/same sequence I have posted in answer. Also obviously, all must under same DB.