# function with table name input

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-function

I need to create a function in sql server that receives a table name. 
The table name will be used to create a select statement and return a result set.
The result set will be processed and returned back.

Something like this:

```
SELECT * FROM @table_name WHERE id=1
```

Comment: In order to pass a table name to a *function* and run SQL on the table, you need dynamic SQL.  SQL Server user-defined functions don't support dynamic SQL.  Hence, this would not seem to be possible:  http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms191320.aspx.

Comment: @JonEgerton . . . I strongly disagree that that question is a duplicate.  This question is about *functions* not *stored procedures*.  The restrictions are quite different in SQL Server.

Comment: Gordon is correct.  Dynamic SQL is not supported in a UDF.  So how about alternatives. How about receiving a table as a parameter http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1609115/pass-table-as-parameter-into-sql-server-udf