# Table as input in table-value function

Tags: sql-server

```
create function PRODUCT_CULC (@PRODUCT_KEY AS VARCHAR(50), @PROD_TABLE *AS TABLE*) RETURNS TABLE RETURN  SELECT
```

How do I get in **table-valued function** table as a input value?
(What I wrote on the exemple are incorrect)

> create function [db_123].[PRODUCT_CULC]
>
> (@PRODUCT_KEY AS VARCHAR(50))
>
> ```
> RETURNS TABLE
> RETURN (
> select TOP 3 ACCOUNT_KEY
> From db_123.ORDERS ORD
>  JOIN db_123.ACCOUNT ACCOUNT ON ORDERS.ACCOUNT_SK = ACCOUNT.ENTITY_SK
>  JOIN db_123.PRODUCT PRODUCT ON PRODUCT.ENTITY_SK = ORD.PRODUCT_SK AND PRODUCT.PRODUCT_KEY = @PRODUCT_KEY
>
> );
> ```

I want instead of using the "orders" table, get the name of a table on which I will do the query .. that could be the same function I will want to do in cases other than the table orders

Comment: what exactly you need? Do you have to pass table value function from c# to Sql server?

Comment: no, I works only with sql server.

Comment: ok you have to pass table value to a function.

Comment: This is maybe what you need https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1609115/pass-table-as-parameter-into-sql-server-udf

Comment: @ViewedArticleIds dbo.ArticaleTableType readonly; you can set table function argument like this. Did it help you?

Comment: exactly. I need to move a table value so that in the function I can do a query on it.

Comment: you can use table value like this inside function @ViewedArticleIds dbo.ArticaleTableType readonly.