# Subquery as parameter into SQL Server UDF

Tags: sql, sql-server, subquery, user-defined-functions, table-variable

My question is similar to [this](https://stackoverflow.com/q/1609115/8027036).

I made a scalar function like follows:

```sql
CREATE FUNCTION [dbo].[MyFunction](@table [TableModel] READONLY)
RETURNS DECIMAL(18, 6) AS
BEGIN
    DECLARE @sql NVARCHAR(MAX), @params NVARHCAR(MAX), @value DECIMAL(16, 8);
    SELECT @sql = formula, @params = params FROM formulas WHERE id = (SELECT TOP 1 id_formula FROM @table)
    EXEC sp_executesql @sql, @params, @table=@table, @value=@value OUTPUT;
    RETURN @value;
END
```

Where a formula SQL could be something like:

```sql
SELECT @value = SUM(value) / AVG(value) FROM @table
```

And it could have more columns if needed.

The model table looks like so:

```sql
CREATE TYPE [dbo].[TableModel] AS TABLE(
    [formula] INT NOT NULL,
    [value] DECIMAL(16, 8) NOT NULL
)
```

And I want to use it like so:

```sql
SELECT  od.id, od.col1, od.col2, 
        dbo.MyFunction((SELECT id.formula, id.value FROM #raw_data id WHERE id.id = od.id)) as result
FROM    #data od
GROUP BY od.id, od.col1, od.col2
```

Where the ID unique and multiple rows will have the same id.

Basically, what I'm trying to do in a single query I want to call a function that has a table parameter. But I want this table to be a subquery.

I'm aware that you can call the function with a table variable as mentioned in this [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/1609200/8027036).

Is this possible in any way? I'm having this error at executing:

> Msg 116, Level 16, State 1, Line 30 
> Only one expression can be specified in the select list when the subquery is not introduced with EXISTS.

Comment: Expression `(SELECT id.value FROM #raw_data id WHERE id.id = od.id)` is not  of  the `[TableModel]` type.  Sql server has no way to cast a derived table to a user defined table type. You want a [user defined aggregate](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/statements/create-aggregate-transact-sql?view=sql-server-ver15)

Comment: Your function doesn't even use the `@table` variable, it's not clear exactly what you are trying to do but you probably need a table-valued function you can use with `apply`

Comment: @Stu you were right, I edited the question. Unfortunately, table-valued function is not an option. What I want is to pass a subquery into a scalar function to retrieve a single value.

Comment: @Serg Thanks for the reply! I'll check out the user-defined aggregations.

Comment: A table-valued function is always the preferred choice, why is it not an option?

Comment: @Stu I edited my question. I don't think that table-value functions fits in this scenario where I try to execute some SQL with ```sp_executesql```.

Comment: Well you can't use dynamic SQL in a function either.  If you describe what you're trying to achieve instead of describing how you're trying to achieve it, there may be a workable approach.

Comment: @BrunoRamirez you've changed the scenario of the question and what you have presented cannot work, it appears you have an XY problem.

Comment: @DavidBrowne-Microsoft your right, my bad. For some reason, I was able to execute a function with a sp_executesql inside of it but it was my fault from the beginning. Despite that, I was able to achieve what I was trying to do with unpivot. Thanks, everyone!

Comment: This question is so full of syntax errors, it's hard to know what you are trying to do. It seems you want to execute dynamic SQL, which you can't do in a function. Perhaps you should rethink your data model